# What sort of recursion is this?

Tags: racket

Is this tail recursion ? I think it is but I am not sure. Also, when I run the program if I input a list `(1 2 3)`, its output is `(4 3 2)`. Why is that ? Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
     (define (add1-iter a-list)
     (define (add1-helper curr-list result-list)
    (if (null? curr-list)
        result-list
    (add1-helper (cdr curr-list)
                 (cons (add1 (car curr-list))
                       result-list))))
    (add1-helper a-list '()))
```

Comment: Why did you edit your question to delete all the code, after Sylwester spent time answering it for you??

Comment: I just rolled back the edit to restore the code.

Answer (score 3):

It's tail recursion.

You have an accumulator (result-list) which you build your list from the end to the beginning while you are iterating the elements in the source from the beginning to the end. It's not possible to get it the same order with tail recursion.